# How to get the last comma separated data stored in a variable? - Progress 4gl

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am new to progress 4gl but don't know how to write a logic to get the last value after the last comma and last before value using comma separator. Please help

```
define variable cdata as character no-undo initial "1,14,13,45".
define variable lvc_data1 as character no-undo.
define variable lvc_data2 as character no-undo.
```

**Expected Results to be assigned (using only separator):**

lvc_data1 = "45"

lvc_data2 = "1,14,13"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last element is easy with ENTRY and NUM-ENTRIES. For the other ones, I'm using SUBSTRING and R-INDEX:

```
define variable cdata as character no-undo initial "1,14,13,45".
define variable lvc_data1 as character no-undo.
define variable lvc_data2 as character no-undo.

MESSAGE ENTRY (NUM-ENTRIES (cdata), cdata) SKIP 
        SUBSTRING (cdata, 1, R-INDEX (cdata, ",") - 1 ) 
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFORMATION BUTTONS OK.
```

Comment: How to validate entry function for the error "Entry 0 is outside the range of list . (560)"

Comment: ``num-entries`` will return 0 if the string is empty, so you will need to add a check, ``if cdata > '' then entry( num-entries( cdata ), cdata ) else ''`` or ``entry( max( 1, num-entries( cdata ) ), cdata )``